# Cleaning and stripping of strings/HTML - Python

Tags: python, html, string, unicode, sanitization

I have a set of questions, of which I do not have an answer to.

1) **Stripping lists of string**

```
input:
'item1,   item2, \t\t\t item3, \n\n\n \t, item4, , , item5, '

output:
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

**Anything more efficient than doing the following?**

```
[x.strip() for x in l.split(',') if x.strip()]
```

2) **Cleaning/Sanitizing HTML**

keeping basic tags e.g. strong, p, br, ...

removing malicious javascript, css and divs

3) **Unicode handling...**

what would you recommend for dealing with unicode parsed within documents?

---

Any ideas? :) Thanks guys!

Comment: Please split your question into 3, that makes the questions much more helpful for people who might search for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to write multiple cascading generators, particularly if I want to some output to be part of a test:

```
stripped_iter = (x.strip() for x in l.split(','))
non_empty_iter = (x for x in stripped_iter if x)
```

The inspiration is Beazley's [presentation on coroutines](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/).

Answer (score 2):

For the first one you can use split then a list comprehension to trim the extra whitespace:

```
result = [x.strip() for x in i.split(',')]
```

And to remove the empty strings from the list:

```
result = [x for x in result if x]
```

Comment: It would have to be result = [x.strip() for x in i.split(',') if x.strip()], was hoping there would be a more efficient way of doing this though. Well thanks anyway

Comment: btw [x.strip() for x in i.split(',') if x.strip()] does both at the same time :)

Comment: @RadiantHex: ... by performing the `strip` twice. This answer would be better if the first operation were a generator, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

To clean HTML use [**lxml.html**](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html)

```
import lxml.html
text = lxml.html.fromstring("...")
text.text_content()
```

Comment: thanks :) but it doesn't really clean/sanitize the HTML. I just need br, p, strong, italic, span elements :)

Comment: A good way to sanitise HTML is to parse it into a DOM, remove all the elements, attributes, and URL-schemes that aren't known-safe, and serialise back to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat of a beginner at python web development, but for cleaning/sanitizing html I have found that the [markdown2](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/) library has some very nice features. You can use it with the [MarkItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markdown/) jQuery-based editor. They may not solve all your problems but might help you do a lot of work in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use the strip method

2) you can use sanitize , http://wonko.com/post/sanitize

3) some unicode tips here: http://blog.trydionel.com/2010/03/23/some-unicode-tips-for-ruby/

Comment: Erm... the question appears to be Python, rather than Ruby? The way the two languages handle Unicode is very, very different.

Answer (score 1):

1) `[j.strip() for j in a.split(',') if j.strip()]`

2) check [tidy](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html)